# Deleting everything in directory except for two specific folders

Tags: unix, command-line, command

I'm trying to delete everything within a directory except for two folders that I know the names of. Let's say that the two folders are called "dont_delete1" and "dont_delete2". And within the the current directory, other folder and files exist.

I have tried

```
rm -r !(dont_delete1|dont_delete2)
```

but that requires me to `shopt -s extglob` which due to certain restraint, I can't use.

So I turned to

```
find . \! -name [folder name] -delete
```

I've tested it out on a single folder and it works. But I can't figure out a way to use the above command for multiple folders. I've tried all sorts of commands that I thought would work but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of different solutions, here's one thats easy to understand:

```
$ls | grep -v dont_delete1 | grep -v  dont_delete2 | xargs rm -rf
```